# Can't find header file in .lib

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm working with an Mcp2221, a chip for USB to I2C.

On the Microchip website is a dll to work with the Mcp2221 https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/MCP2221 I have downloaded the "MCP2221 DLL (v2.2.1)"

In the downloaded zip under unmanaged => lib I copied the mcp2221_dll_um_x64.lib to the directory D:\createJNIDll

MCP2221 DLL (v2.2.1)\unmanaged\lib\ content:

[image: Zip Content]

D:\createJNIDll\ content:

[image]

Now I working with Code::Blocks.
I created a new Project and in this Project a file named "main.cpp"

Under Settings => Compiler => Search directories I have added "D:\createJNIDll\" to Compiler and Linker.

Under Rightclick on my Project => Build options => Linker settings I have added "D:\createJNIDll\mcp2221_dll_um_x64.lib"

My main.cpp looks like this:

```
#include "mcp2221_dll_um.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    wchar_t* res;
    int i = Mcp2221_GetLibraryVersion(res);
    std::cout << i << ": " << res << std::endl;
}
```

When I try to build and run the Project I get the Error:

> fatal error: mcp2221_dll_um.h: No such file or directory

In the lib directory is a mcp2221_dll_um.h file as you can see in the picture above. So I expected that this header is in the .lib but I'm not 100% sure.

Can anybody help me to fix this problem that I can use the .lib in my project?

Answer (score 0):

> So I expected that this header is in the .lib but I'm not 100% sure

What gave you *that* idea?

The header is a file on disk. You've pointed the linker to the `.lib` file, but the compiler has no idea where to look for the header. Add that location to your include directories.

Comment: I added the Header to the location of the .lib and now it compiles, Thanks. I think I have a little bit of misunderstanding lib files. My next problem is that I can't call any functions. I get "undefined reference to `_imp__Mcp2221_GetLibraryVersion@4'

Comment: @Morchul [Here you go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix).